# Taqueria/Ligo install problems

Tags: ligo

I'm trying to run through this tutorial on DApp development with Ligo (https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-ligo-marketplace/) and am running into an error.

```
TAQ_LIGO_IMAGE=ligolang/ligo:0.73.0 taq ligo --command "install @ligo/fa"
```

gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: FYI : esy dependency will be remove in few weeks

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce it locally so it's hard to find the solution.

FYI You are using docker, esy is directly installed inside so you should not have to install esy before.

Some clues :

When you run this command, the command behind should be :

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":"$PWD" -w "$PWD" ligolang/ligo:0.73.0 install @ligo/fa
```

Can you try it to verify it's not related to taqueria ?

Maybe you should verify what is inside your image by running :

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash ligolang/ligo:0.73.0
```

Maybe you can also try to check the shasum :

```
docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' ligolang/ligo:0.73.0
ligolang/ligo@sha256:6d9839ba3ca6190fb6d8cf39f76c618ed54af924a5c9187deea68a7e10b087b8
```

Comment: 1. clue --> error: No solution found:
No package matching:
blindripper -> vite-compatible-readable-stream@^3.6.1
resolving request vite-compatible-readable-stream@^3.6.1
esy: exiting due to errors above
error while install packages


2. --> looks good; image is loaded and files look ok. 

3. --> SHA same as yours
6d9839ba3ca6190fb6d8cf39f76c618ed54af924a5c9187deea68a7e10b087b8

Comment: Are you usign a package.json file or a esy.json file ?

Comment: Looks like you have a package.json, If you are on taq, probably you are building a dApp, and so you have to use a esy.json (it'll be not the case in ligo 1.0.0 only a ligo.json will be accepted  ) 

To intialize it you have to create esy.json file containing `{}`

Comment: I did create an esy.json file (just like the mentioned tutorial said).

Comment: Weird, esy try to install your package.json here.. Any chance to have access to your code somewhere to see if the issue come from your local or the project itself ?

Comment: I really started with a fresh VS Code and step by step followed the NFT Wine Tutorial (see Topic).

Comment: With V1.0.0 esy is no more used. So your issue should not be reproducible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `esy` using `npm install -g esy`, more info can be found here: https://esy.sh/

Comment: Same error as before.